# Activerecord regex search with mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, sanitizer

I want to perform following search request

```
.where("url REGEXP ?", '^/gallery/\d+')
```

but sanitizer spoils expression and i get this:

```
^/gallery/\\\\d+
```

how force skip sanitizing for this condition?

Answer (score 1):

the whole point about using `?` in where conditions is to sanitize the string.

if you are using database specific queries, it's always a good idea to mention it in your tags. i assume that you want to use the MySQL REGEXP function.

if you don't want it to be sanitized just write this: `where("url REGEXP '^/gallery/\d+'")`